# Alcatel one touch not found in ADB

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to connect my alcatel one touch to my PC over USB for use with android studio.

`adb usb` outputs `error: device not found`
`adb devices` doesn't output any device name :

```
List of devices attached
(blank line)
```

My phone does show up with `lsusb` though (2nd line)

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c531 Logitech, Inc  
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 1bbb:9017 T & A Mobile Phones  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5710 IMC Networks UVC VGA Webcam  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've already tried to `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create udev rules

   `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
2. Insert this lines, save and exit

   `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1bbb", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`
3. Restart udev

   `sudo service udev restart`
4. Enable USB Debug in your phone (In Android 4.2.x and up Developer Options is hidden, to make it visible, do the following)

   - Tap seven times in Build Number: Settings > About Phone > Build Number
   - You will get a message saying you have enabled Developer Options or something like that, go back to Settings and you will see Developer Options in there.
5. Connect phone with USB cable
6. Open Terminal and type

   `adb devices`

I have Alcatel OneTouch Pop C7 (7041D)

```
List of devices attached  
6H9PY5ZPJV9HO7R4    device
```